# How can I connect a Raspberry Pi to a 29V KNX bus?

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi, knx

I have a smart home system using KNX, and I want to expand to it using my own displays and sensors. I also want to replace some KNX devices with my own devices (which I will program myself)

The KNX bus conveniently runs through my entire house to any place I would want to connect a device, so it would be easiest to have a Raspberry Pi (or similar) run off the 29V supply voltage and directly connect to the KNX bus to read and write signals.

How would be the best way to do this? Do I get a transformer for every single device I want to connect, to step the voltage down to the 5V the Raspberry Pi runs at? Or do devices exist (similar to a Pi) that run at 29V?

Comment: Cheapest / quickest way would be getting a COTS DC/DC converter (assuming KNX is DC) and dropping down the voltage to that acceptable by the Pi. Seems like KNX might be common enough that someone makes an existing KNX / ~24 VDC -> USB-C adapter you can use?

Comment: You’d want to read the KNX specs carefully as even with a dc/dc converter, the load may be over 500mA, so your power supply and cabling will need to be suitably rated. You don’t want to burn down your house.

Answer (score 1):

KNX is not exactly DC since there is an AC component; the KNX bus devices' power and serial communication are on the same twisted pair (TP). You should certainly NOT use the KNX TP wires (red/black) to power your Pi - even through a converter - as this will most likely cause problems and overload your KNX bus power supply.

Your KNX cable might have a spare pair of wires (yellow/white) that you could use to supply extra low voltage DC to the Pi.  Consider that the maximum current normally carried by a KNX TP line (determined by the largest commercially available KNX power supply) is 1280mA @ 30 V. You might want to run a voltage higher than 5V (maybe 12V or 24V) across the yellow/white pair and use a small converter at each Pi.

The company Weinzierl make a KNX module which may be available from KNX distributors in your region. It can connect directly to the GPIO of the Pi for UART communication between the Pi and the KNX bus.

https://weinzierl.de/en/products/knx-baos-modul-838/

https://weinzierl.de/en/download-baos/